# Detect system hibernate(S4) from .NET Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, windows-services

I am writing a windows service application in `.NET/C#`.

My service has to be notified when the system enters in `hibernation(S4)`. How to do this in code?

Looks like `ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent()` method does not notify about the hibernation(S4) event.

Comment: [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187658/21567), there is no difference between hibernate and suspend from the point of view of detecting one or the other. So you would handle `QuerySuspend`  and/or `Suspend` power states.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a way to specifically identify whether it is a Sleep or a Hibernate? PowerBroadcastStatus value caught seems to be "Suspend" for both cases.

Comment: That's the whole point of the linked Q&A - there is no way to differentiate them.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any way to capture all the system power events(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5) in windows service?. Our intention is to inform app that how many times system has entered all these states.

Comment: From all *I* know, you can't. Again, there is no obvious distinction between the kind of "suspend" the system is performing in the notification it sends to applications (incl. services). Also see [PBT_APMSUSPEND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-apmsuspend) native message. There might be some heuristic or other ways to find out, but I don't know them.